# Would the notes used in this chord make up just a plain G chord?

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-theory

I am transcribing "Bell Bottom Blues" on the guitar. In the intro picking I think they're using this chord that just uses the notes in this order: G, D, B, G. Would this be called a G chord? The fingering is different from what you'd normally play for a G chord (I am using third fret E string, open D string, 4th fret G string then pull off to open G), so I'm curious to know if there's a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G, B and D - in any order - comprise a G major chord.   Yes, there are LOTS of alternative voicings possible!

Comment: Is this bordering on embarrassing - or is it just embarrassing?

Comment: Can't we just let it be elementary?